# Javascript local variables - is it worth using them?

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, local

It gets said a lot that local variables are faster than globals in JavaScript Eg:

```
function ()
{
     // Local variable
     var a = 9
}
```

For instance, I've been thinking of aliasing the global Math object to a local Mathl variable or alternatively aliasing specific (much used) functions to a local variable/function like Mathround() instead of using Math.round().

Now the things that I'm thinking of doing this with (eg Math.round() ) can be used plenty of times per animation frame (50ish) and there could be 60 frames per second. So quite a few lookups would be avoided if I do this. - and that's just one example of something I could do it with. There'd be lots of similar variables I could alias.

So my question is - is this really worth it? Is the difference tangible when there's so  many lookups being avoided?

Comment: You could measure the difference. Do an experiment!

Comment: You should **not** assume that `x.y()` will work the same as `a = x.y; a();`

Comment: This is not a matter of slow vs fast. It's a matter of global vs local, and 99% of the time you want local, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Don't bother about (potential) performance improvements like aliasing built-ins like `Math` unless you have a good reason to. The real reason to use local variables for your own things whenever possible is code quality.

Comment: With regard to Google's v8 (as well as some of the other engines) you might check out this video on how they do performance optimizations:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw  One key take away is they watch your code execute and then optimize around that.  So the odds are good that, on newer engines, after a few executions either approach will even up as long as your code is well written and thus predictable.

Comment: @IngoBürk don't forget that you're much less likely to run into variable name conflicts when you use a local variable, too.

Comment: I still have no idea why new programmers are obsessed with these sorts of micro-optimizations. I really wish I could understand what is in their heads, because it would make it easier to explain to them why the answer to their question at this point in their development is "mu".

Comment: @lwburk Because they're extolled by people like Doug Crockford. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford

Comment: @Paul S That's a very good point

Answer (score 0):

Lookups will be faster if you scope parent-scope variables locally. How much faster? Is the difference noticable? Only you can tell by measuring the performance of your code.

It isin't that rare to see the `document` being aliased to a local variable.

Have a look at [this part](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/Element.html#Ext-Element) of the ExtJS library for instance.

```
(function() {
    var DOC = document,
```

However like already stated, beware blindly aliasing object member functions because you might run into `this` value issues.

E.g.

```
var log = console.log;

log('test'); //TypeError: Illegal invocation

//you could use bind however
log = console.log.bind(console);
```

Comment: Aliasing in libraries that will me minimized is also often used to allow minimizing tools to do a better job.

Comment: Correct, the purpose of aliasing in that code snippet is for minification, not performance.

Comment: It can, but in this case I highly doubt it has any measurable impact. Also, having wrote said code, I can say for sure the reason was minification!

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Oh, I see, well I can't really argue with that one ;) However after gzipping, I wonder if there's really a crucial difference in size between aliasing or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether it's worth it, then it's probably not. In other words, you should address performance issues *when they happen* by identifying, measuring, and testing *situation-specific* alternatives.

It's hard enough to write clear, readable, maintainable code when you set out to write something humans can understand. It's a lot harder if you set out trying to write something that computers can execute *faster* (before you even know what faster *means* in terms of your application). **Focus on clarity and address performance problems as they arise.**

As for your specific example. If you're dying to know the answer, [then *test it*](http://jsperf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this code:

```
for(...) {
  someFunc(); 
  var y = Math.cos(x);
  ...
}
```

To execute the `Math.cos(x)` the JS VM must a) compute location of global Math object and b) get `cos` property of it. Just in case someone inside that `someFunc()` doesn't do crazy things as this for example:

```
Math = {};
```

In general in JS access to local variable is similar (if not exact) to access to array element by known index. Access to global objects is pretty much always look-up by key in maps.